# ReactJS: obtaining JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async.js

I have component named 'App':

```
export default class App extends Component {

    state = {
        data: {
            id: null,
            created: null
        },
        clicked: false,
        loading: true
    };

    render() {
        const data = this.state.data.id === null ? null : <Data data={this.state.data}/>;
        const title = this.state.clicked ? <TitleDone/> : <Title/>;

        return (
            <div>
                {title}
                <div className="main">
                    <button
                        className=" btn btn-outline-secondary"
                        onClick={() => {
                            this.setState(() => {
                                return {
                                    data: api.getResource(),
                                    clicked: true
                                };
                            });
                        }}>
                        Нажать
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="main">
                    {data}
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When I press Button, component 'Api' sending request to backend and I reseive JSON with 2 fields: id, created.

Request:

```
getResource = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`${this._apiPath}${this._logUrl}`);

    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Could not fetch ${this._logUrl}` +
            `, received ${res.status}`)
    }
    return await res.json();
};
```

res.json():

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Network.Response:

```
{"id":87,"created":"2019-04-18 17:26:28.948"}
```

As we see, JSON wrapped into Promise.
It comming to 'App' as undefined, and after response this.state.data looking like:

```
data: {
    id: undefined,
    created: undefined
}
```

Please give me advice, how to obtain data correctly and send it to component 'App'. Or, may be, there is another way to do it?

Comment: `api.getResource()` is probably an async call which is why you are getting return value `undefined`.

Comment: An `async` function always returns a promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getResource` is asynchronous, so you need to wait for the promise that is returned to be resolved before you put it in your component state.

```
<button
  className=" btn btn-outline-secondary"
  onClick={async () => {
    this.setState({
      data: await api.getResource(),
      clicked: true
    });
  }}
>
  Нажать
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

And you do not need await for return res.json()

```
getResource = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`${this._apiPath}${this._logUrl}`);

    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Could not fetch ${this._logUrl}` +
            `, received ${res.status}`)
    }
    return res.json();
};
```